# Facebook App Insights user can't see app in dashboard

Tags: facebook

When I invite people to my insights, they can see that they are invited, but when they go to Developer.facebook.com/apps the list is empty.

If I set them to Developer, they can see the app. What do I do wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link for the InSights for non-developers are: http://www.facebook.com/insights/